# Is there a way to change the layout direction for my app in android

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, arabic

I need to change the layout direction inside my app, from LTR to RTL and vise versa, I looked there is no clear solution online, is this process simple or not, I mean it must be property inside the app you can change this property easily for all the layouts in your app, any ideas?

Note: I want to change the language and the layout just inside my app.

Comment: Do you mean you need to see what it will look like on devices set to a RTL language?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I mean I have a client who wants to add the Arabic language inside my app, this Language is RTL, but the user has options to change to English also which is LTR

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your device in RTL mode, you can do this in the develop settings (Force RTL layout direction).
2. You should ensure that all your layouts don't use "left" and "right" properties, e.g `layout_marginLeft`, instead they should use `layout_marginStart` and `layout_marginEnd`.

This will mean that when run on device that's set to read right to left (e.g arabic), all the layouts will mirror correctly.

If you don't want to change the whole device into RTL, paste this in the `onCreate` method of **every** activity in your app (paste it before `super` and before you inflate the content view.

Java: `getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);`
Kotlin: `window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL`

(I don't believe you'll need to add this to every fragment, only activities).

Comment: But I want to change the language just inside my app, not all the device!

Comment: Understood, I have updated my answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can force RTL like this

```
window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
```

You can also set it to `LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR` for left-to-right layout direction

Comment: You mean in each activity or fragment I must but this Line?

Comment: As far as I know, it's only needed for activities. And you don't really need to manually add it to all of your activities. Just make a BaseActivitry class and make all your activities inherit from it.